# sklearn LogisticRegression does not accept csr_matrix

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, logistic-regression

I am a newby and I have to classify the words of a lexicon according to the De Pauw and Wagacha (1998) method (basically, maxent on char n-grams).   The data is very large (500 000 entries and millions of n-grams).  So I must load the samples as a sparse matrix. But I ran into a problem.

`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X,y)` says it does not accept scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix training vectors.  I got this error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test-LR-4.py", line 8, in <module>
>     clf.fit(X,y)
>   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 441, in fit
>     % type(X))
> ValueError: Training vectors should be array-like, not <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
> ```

for the following script:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
X = sp.csr_matrix([[0, 1, 2],[1, 2, 3],[3, 2, 1]])
y = np.array(range(3))
clf=LogisticRegression(dual=True)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? I'm pretty sure that should work....

Comment: Works fine in the current version. The OP might be using a version that still had the separate `sklearn.linear_model.sparse` module.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I upgraded to 0.13.1 and this solved my problem. --Nabil Hathout

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments by @Andreas and @Fred Foo, upgrading the `sklearn` version (> 0.13) will solve the problem.